# Add new field to nodeJs model with mongodb

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb, typescript, model

I have a user  model in nodeJs api and working with mongo db and Angular as frontEnd framework, I want to to add a new field to my user model, What I did is add the field named : "municipalityDateChange" and try to to send a http request from angular to nodeApi and log the response, the user does contain the new field which is null by default !

```
import mongoose, {
  Schema
} from 'mongoose'
import mongooseDelete from 'mongoose-delete'
import bcrypt from 'bcrypt'
import crypto from 'crypto'

const userSchema = new Schema({
  firstName: {
    type: String
  },
  lastName: {
    type: String
  },
  phone: {
    type: Number
  },
  email: {
    type: String
  },
  hashedPassword: {
    type: String
  },
  address: {
    type: String
  },
  city: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'City'
  },
  municipalityDateChange: {
    type: Date,
    default: null
  },
  service: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Service'
  },
  postalCode: {
    type: String
  },
  gender: {
    type: String
  },
  age: {
    type: Number
  },
  birthDate: {
    type: Date
  },
  profession: {
    type: String
  },
  tokens: [{
    token: {
      type: String,
      // required: true
    }
  }],
  token: {
    type: String
  },
  type: {
    type: String,
    enum: ['superAdmin', 'president', 'chefService', 'secretaireGeneral', 'conseillerMunicipal', 'citoyen'],
    default: 'citoyen'
  },
  activated: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: false
  },
  suspended: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: false
  },
  avatar: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'File'
  },
  confirmationCode: {
    type: Number
  },
  resetPasswordCode: {
    type: Number
  },
  codeSent: {
    type: Number,
    default: 0
  },
  allInfo: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: false
  },
  propositions: [{
    evaluation: {
      type: String,
      enum: ['like', 'dislike']
    },
    proposition: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'Proposition'
    }
  }],
  commissions: [{
    type: String
  }]
}, {
  timestamps: true
})

userSchema.virtual('password').set(function (password) {
  this.hashedPassword = bcrypt.hashSync(password, bcrypt.genSaltSync(10))
})

function calculateAge(birthDate, otherDate) {
  birthDate = new Date(birthDate);
  otherDate = new Date(otherDate);

  var years = (otherDate.getFullYear() - birthDate.getFullYear())

  if (otherDate.getMonth() < birthDate.getMonth() ||
    otherDate.getMonth() == birthDate.getMonth() && otherDate.getDate() < birthDate.getDate()) {
    years--;
  }

  return years
}

userSchema.pre('save', function (next) {
  this.age = calculateAge(this.birthDate, new Date())
  next()
})

userSchema.methods = {
  comparePassword(candidatePassword) {
    return bcrypt.compareSync(candidatePassword, this.hashedPassword)
  }
}

userSchema.methods.generateAuthToken = async function () {
  // Generate an auth token for the user
  const user = this
  const token = crypto
    .createHash('sha256')
    .update(crypto.randomBytes(48).toString('hex'))
    .digest('hex')
  user.tokens = user.tokens.concat({
    token
  })

  await user.save()
  return token
}

userSchema.plugin(mongooseDelete, {
  overrideMethods: 'all',
  deletedAt: true,
  deletedBy: true
})

export default mongoose.model('User', userSchema)
```

*** user controller***

```
export async function getOne (req, res) {
  try {
    const user = await User.findById({
      _id: req.params.id
    })
      .populate('avatar')
      // .populate('city')
      // .populate('service')
      .select('firstName lastName type avatar phone email gender age postalCode address profession activated suspended municipalityDateChange')
      .lean()
      .exec()

    user.avatar ? user.avatar = user.avatar.filePath : delete user.avatar

    return res.json(user)
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
    return res.status(500).end()
  }
}
```

***ts***

```
  this.http.get('api/user').subscribe(user => {
      console.log("current user", user)
      this.currentUser = user;
})
```

the log does not show that the user have the new filed !

what should I do in thins case ? update all my collection doc or there is other method to set new filed in my model ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to remove the default key for **municipalityDateChange** to :

```
{
    type: Date
}
```

Comment: if it is still not displayed, try to add required:true to it.